# this where and that where

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, relative-clauses, adjuncts

> [i] Well, as we reported earlier the chief executive of the Dutch airport **where** the flight departed says 27 Australians were on board. ([ABC news](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2014/s4048706.htm))
>   [ii] There was **where** Vadinho used to sit on the wall, at his feet the sea dotted with fishing skiffs. (Dona Flor and Her Two Husbands, translated by Alfred A.Knoptf)

Someone says *where* of [i] is (relative) [adverb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_adverb#Relative_.28adjectival.29_clause), another one says preposition (CGEL,p.1050), and another one says adjunctizer (by Bas Aarts). Okay aside from whatever names they call it, there is antecedent in [i], and there isn’t any in [ii] - In the latter case, antecedent is freed or fused; ‘*where*’ of [i] means ‘from which’, ‘*where*’ of [ii] means ‘the place in which’. This is the difference between the two, isn’t it?

Comment: @user3169 It’s exactly what the translation read - I don’t know if it was the translating division’s - it is written that this books is translated by Alfred A. Knopf, Inc - original intention. I’m afraid there are some who think the structure is quite right: (from COCA)

 And there was where they burrowed a hole in his skull to relieve pressure on the ‘brain.

But there was where the girls must have been.
There was where the line should have been drawn

Comment: I think you're right, as far as it goes; but I have to wonder how the relationship between the two terms linked by the copula *was* in [ii] is distinguished semantically from the relationship between the two terms linked by anaphora in [i]!

Comment: @StoneyB I think the words, free or fused, imply the semantic difference. Because of this, in [ii] the clause has the meaning of NP; in [i] adjective. For this reason, I think, Bas Aarts says ‘where’ in [i] is adjunctizer, ‘where’ in [ii] is complementizer.

Comment: Those are *names* for the difference; but they refer to syntactic roles, not semantic distinctions.

Comment: @StoneyB, Listenever. I guess [ii] is likely a referring back, for example, *[a narrative about a place]. There was where Vadinho used to sit on the wall, ...*. And both *there* and *where* refer to that place. It's also possible that it's a referring forward to arouse the reader's curiosity. (If [ii] was the first sentence in the passage, it would make the reader wonder for a while, "Where is that place that Vadinho used to sit on the wall?". I couldn't find the original text on the web, though.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I think we're on the borders of "grammar" now and about to sliip over into discourse analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it. There is little difference between free and bound relative clauses except their syntactic deployment. You may freely switch either clause into the opposite use:

> That airport is [<sub>FREE RELATIVE</sub> where the flight departed].
>   From the spot [<sub>BOUND RELATIVE</sub> where Vadinho used to sit on the wall] the fishing skiffs were visible, dotted at his feet.

There are constraints on what pronouns may be used in the different contexts (for instance, *-ever* forms are not used in bound relatives), but the difference at bottom is between complementary and adjunctive use.